# GetSymbolInfo().Symbol returning null on AttributeSyntax

Tags: roslyn

I have a custom attribute I'm using to test a Roslyn code analyzer I'm writing:

```
[AttributeUsage( validOn: AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true )]
public class DummyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DummyAttribute( string arg1, Type arg2 )
    {
    }

    public int TestField;
}
```

which decorates another test class:

```
[Dummy( "", typeof( string ) )]
[Dummy( "test", typeof( int ) )]
[Dummy( "test", typeof( int ) )]
public class J4JLogger<TCalling> : IJ4JLogger<TCalling>
{
```

But when I call GetSymbolInfo() on it with the semantic model it's defined in:

```
model.GetSymbolInfo( attrNode ).Symbol
```

the value of Symbol is null.

What's odd is that the GetSymbolInfo() call works perfectly well for attribute classes defined in the Net Core library (e.g., `AttributeUsage`).

Both `Dummy` and `J4JLogger` are defined in the same project. I create my compilation unit by parsing the files individually (e.g., `J4JLogger` is parsed and analyzed separately from `Dummy`) so when I'm parsing `J4JLogger` there is no reference to the assembly containing both `J4JLogger` and `Dummy`.

Could the problem be that `model` doesn't actually contain the `Dummy` class I think it does? Is there a way to check what's in the semantic model? Do I have to include a reference to the assembly whose source file I'm analyzing in the semantic model?

**Corrected Parsing Logic**

My original parsing logic parsed each file into a syntax tree independent of all its sister source files. The correct way to parse source files -- at least when they depend on each other -- is something like this:

```
protected virtual (CompilationUnitSyntax root, SemanticModel model) ParseMultiple( string primaryPath, params string[] auxPaths )
{
    if( !IsValid )
        return (null, null);

    CSharpCompilation compilation;
    SyntaxTree primaryTree;

    var auxFiles = auxPaths == null || auxPaths.Length == 0
        ? new List<string>()
        : auxPaths.Distinct().Where( p => !p.Equals( primaryPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) );

    try
    {
        var auxTrees = new List<SyntaxTree>();

        primaryTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText( File.ReadAllText( primaryPath ) );
        auxTrees.Add( primaryTree );

        foreach( var auxFile in auxFiles )
        {
            var auxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText( File.ReadAllText( auxFile ) );
            auxTrees.Add( auxTree );
        }

        compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create( ProjectDocument.AssemblyName )
            .AddReferences( GetReferences().ToArray() )
            .AddSyntaxTrees( auxTrees );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        Logger.Error<string>( "Configuration failed, exception message was {0}", e.Message );
        return (null, null);
    }

    return (primaryTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot(), compilation.GetSemanticModel( primaryTree ));
}
```

A minor gotcha is that AddSyntaxTrees() does not appear to be incremental; you need to add all the relevant syntax trees in one call to AddSyntaxTrees().

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that you have to include all the source files that reference each other (e.g., `Dummy` and `J4JLogger` in my case) in the compilation unit because otherwise the "internal" references (e.g., decorating `J4JLogger` with `Dummy`) won't resolve. I've annotated the question with how I rewrote my parsing logic.